# Flex Google Chrome cache issue

Tags: apache-flex, google-chrome

I have one issue with my web project we use to release a new swf, the older version gets cached in Chrome and you have to clear your cache to see it. The same does not happen in Firefox and IE.

Environment Used: - Web Application (Flex), Browser tested on IE, Firefox and Google Chrome.

Is there any programmatic solution which can help to solve this problem by using JavaScript, HTML or through Flex?

*Solution tried (Does not work): -*

I have the following headers:

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" />

meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-store, no-cache" />

meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0, -1" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a naming convention for your swf that includes the version and build number.  The file name difference will address caching as well as being a best practice for numerous reasons.

It's hard to argue that it's better to just guess which version of the code base "myApp.swf" is versus "myApp.2.1.0015.swf" and knowing immediately.

Here is a good version nomenclature.

http://apr.apache.org/versioning.html

I'm always confused why people are so adverse to a rename operation after compiling.  Make it part of your deployment routine.  Updating a little HTML to point the the appropriate build is not that time consuming.

I promise users won't care if you're builds are actually appropriately named, in fact, I doubt they'll notice other than not having any more caching issues.

If you're re-distributing you're app and patches so much and so often that it is too much hassle for 2 minutes of html to point to the new build, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Not to mention that if you're using ANT to compile, you can script the name change, versioning, etc., and make it 100% automatic.